# Как вернуть индекс следующего элемента, если нет нужного?

Tags: python

А есть возможность получить индекс элемента, а если этого элемента нету то индекс следующего элемента

Например

```
const = 4
l = [1,3,5,8]
p = l[-1] - const
new_l = l[l.index(p):-1]
```

значение 4 нет в списке и он должен вернуть индекс следующего т.е 5.
Простым прибавлением единицы не хочется так, мб есть какой-то метод

Comment: а если массив не отсортированный?

Comment: А если указать не 4, а 1000000, что возваращать? Или строка указана...

Comment: условие что он отсортированный

Comment: @SwaD, то вернуть индекс 1000000

Comment: то есть, если нет элемента, то вернуть этот элемент, а есть элемент больше текущего, то этот новый?

Comment: Ну тогда простым циклом бегите и сравнивайте. Как только ваш const станет меньше текущего элемента, то это оно. Если не нашли ничего, вернуть const

Comment: в отсортированном массиве используйте метод деленая отрезка пополам

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, если элемент, есть , то вернуть индекс этого элемента, а если нет, то вернуть следующий от несуществующего элемента

Comment: вы противоречите себе. вы уже 3 разные вопросы задали. отредактируйте вопрос, допишите все детали и нюансы.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вот такой простой пример решит вашу задачу

```
const = 4
l = [1,3,5,8]

def check(lst, key):
    for i in lst:
        if (i == key) or (i > key):
            return i
    return key

print(check(l, const))
```

Если без фукнций, то можно так

```
const = 4
l = [1,3,5,8]

for i in l:
    if (i == const) or (i > const):
        const = i
        break

print(const)
```

Comment: да, но тут сложность O(n) хотелось меньше я сейчас делаю половинчатым интервалом, как предложил  
Senior Pomidor